# PHP inheritance of abstract classes and overloading

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, abstract

Say I have the following code, is there a way to somehow extend an abstract class on a child and require a different type of argument in the "overloaded" function. I want to insert various types of objects in the Collection through the add function. In some cases, I'd like to insert an Error object, sometimes some other (XYZ) object, and let's say that all those objects extend the same abstract class called Parent.

I would appreciate if somebody could tell me if something like this is even possible, and if it is suggest some ways to accomplish this. Note that production server on which I intend to host the application runs on php 5.6.40.

Thank you in advance.

```php
namespace App;

use App\Models\Parent;

abstract class Collection
{
   protected $collection;

   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->collection = array();
   }

   abstract public function add($key, Parent $item);
}


public class ErrorList extends Collection
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function add($key, Error $item)
    {
       $this->collection[$key] = $item;
    }
}






namespace App\Models;

abstract class Parent {}

public class Error extends Parent {}

public class XYZ extends Parent{}
```

Comment: dont define the type : 
   abstract public function add($key,  $item);

Comment: Still, if I put 
`abstract public function add($key, $item)`
It will throw a fatal error that the two functions are not compatible
Since what I want to do in the child class is
`public function add($key, Error $item){...}`

Comment: do not define type in child classes as well, it should work

Comment: `Furthermore the signatures of the methods must match, i.e. the type hints and the number of required arguments must be the same.` source : https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: @ManishDhruw `Declaration of ChildClass::add() must be compatible with Collection::add($key, $item)`

if I put `abstract public function add($key, $item)` and in the child class `public function add($key, Parent $item){...}`

Comment: @Marino Bjelopera why not avoid type hinting on parent as well as children classes ::
abstract class Collection
{
   abstract public function add($key, $item);
}

public class ErrorList extends Collection
{
   

    public function add($key, $item){}
 
}

Comment: PHP doesn't allow it, so either you use the same type of object if you use the type hinting, or you don't define the type at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
    abstract class Collection
    {
       protected $collection;

       public function __construct()
       {
           $this->collection = array();
       }

       //no type hinting
       abstract public function add($key, $item);
    }


    class ErrorList extends Collection
    {

        // this constructor doing nothing , it can be removed  and     
        // parent constructor will still be called unlike java or any other 
        // OOP
        public function __construct()
        {
           parent::__construct();
        }

        //no type hinting
        public function add($key, $item)
        {
           //code
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're extending a class or implementing an interface the signature must match. You can however implement type checking yourself and type hint in a docblock.

As a side note, `public class` is invalid syntax.

```
abstract class Collection
{
   protected $collection;

   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->collection = array();
   }

   abstract public function add($key, Parent $item);
}


class ErrorList extends Collection
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * @param $key
     * @param Parent|Error $item
     */
    public function add($key, Parent $item)
    {
       if (!($item instanceof Error)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to add object to error list: ' . get_class($item));
        }
       $this->collection[$key] = $item;
    }
}
```